# moving Pages Library items to arraylist or any collection

Tags: content-type, library, pages

I want to move my pages library items to any collection e.g, Arraylist or any other collection, Is that possible?

i want to do this because i want to delete and add again same CT  (that pages library items are using ) from Pages Library, for this i want to temporary move all items to any collection and after performing delete/Add CT action from library, I will add all the items back to library from collection. Is that possible?

Or I Need any other Idea/suggestion to perform this ?

Comment: you want to move them in different list or different site collection?

Comment: I just want to move all items in any collection in my powershell script within same site

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$web = "http://dev/re/ad/wf/"

$orgLibrary = (Get-SPWeb $web).Folders["Approval History - Centre EV"]
$destLibrary = (Get-SPWeb $web).Folders["Approval History - Centre EV1"]

$destFiles = $destLibrary.Files
foreach ($file in $orgLibrary.Files)
{
    $curFile = $file.OpenBinary()
    $destURL = $destFiles.Folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name
    $destFiles.Add($destURL, $curFile, $true)
}
```

http://blog.isaacblum.com/2011/10/04/spfilecollection-class-copy-files-to-another-document-library/